# Why install :i386 packages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i use xubuntu 12.04 amd64 and today i try to install wine:

```
sudo aptitude install wine

Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  attr{a} fonts-horai-umefont{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} 
  libcapi20-3:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
  libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} 
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libhdb9-heimdal{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libkdc2-heimdal{a} 
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libnss-winbind{a} libopenal1:i386{a} 
  libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} 
  libpam-winbind{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} 
  libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} 
  libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} 
  libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} 
  libxcursor1:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} 
  libxrandr2:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} 
  p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} python-dnspython{a} samba{a} 
  samba-dsdb-modules{a} samba-vfs-modules{a} tdb-tools{a} winbind{a} 
  wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} 
  wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
0 пакетов обновлено, 64 установлено новых, 0 пакетов отмечено для удаления, и 111 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо получить 138 MБ архивов. После распаковки 473 MБ будет занято.
Хотите продолжить? [Y/n/?] n
Останов.
```

Whats wrong with it ? Why most packages is :i386 ? How i can fix it ? Can i manually install just amd64 packages?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine executes 32 bit Windows programs. For that purpose, it needs a lot of 32 bit (i386) libraries. This cannot be avoided except by not installing Wine. Wine also cannot use amd64 libraries because these are not usable by 32 bit programs.